# Штаммы гриппа в кавычках (Мичиган и др.)

Tags: пунктуация, выбор-слов, названия

Следующие штаммы: Калифорния, Гонконг, Брисбен, Мичиган. В кавычках Калифорния, Гонконг и Брисбен?

Answer (score 1):

Названия штаммов - вторичное, условное использование собственных существительных Калифорния, Гонконг и прочих. Без кавычек эти слова обозначают конкретный район, территориальную зону, штат,  единственные в своём роде. Поэтому, когда этими же именами называют другой объект,  условные названия необходимо оформлять кавычками. Так же, как названия стихийных бедствий (ураганов, тайфунов, торнадо): тайфун «Джуди», ураган «Катрина», шторм «Ноэль», циклон «Сидр».

***Штаммы "Калифорния", "Гонконг" и "Брисбен", "Мичиган".***

О кавычках можно почитать здесь: [Кавычки, господа, кавычки!](https://writercenter.ru/blog/grammar/kavychki-gospoda-kavychki.html)